# Slide images the screen. Do I really need to write my own "game engine" or use someone elses?

Tags: android

I'm thinking about writing a pretty basic game, which mostly involves sliding images around on the screen when tapped. So tap an image and it slides to one side. Doesn't seem like Android Animations will help me here since those don't actually move the images, just makes it appear moved.

So even though this seems like pretty basic functionality, it seems like I have to write a game loop,etc and implement my own code to handle the "animation" (including some acceleration/deceleration), etc. Not hugely hard or anything, but just seems like overkill. Also using a 3rd party game engine also seems like overkill, just in the time it would take to learn that, and so on.

Am I off base here?

If anyone has any suggestions that might get me pointed in the right direction (links, etc) that would be great. Is there a good way to use Android Animation functionality in this case that I am missing?

Comment: what is the translation like on these images? Is it a slide in on one axis? Do the images slide to a "deck" from different x and y positions?

Answer (score 1):

If you are developing for Honeycomb, it may be as easy with animations. With Honeycomb, there is a whole new strategy to animation. Check out [the blog](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/02/animation-in-honeycomb.html). The premises is that any property or value can be animated, and that includes the view's actual position (and not just look like it moved).

Comment: That does look helpful, but at the moment, I have to be able to target non-Honeycomb devices. At least though they have built out something that addresses some of the issues with the current Animations.

Answer (score 0):

I have built a couple of games using AndEngine (http://andengine.org) I would recommend it for making games for android. And since it is all written in java, it is relativiely easy to integrate it with layouts and other activities.